# Not redirecting to homepage in django

Tags: python, django

I Have a problem in redirecting in django:
code:-

```
def search(requests):
    return HttpResponse("<a href="{% url 'home' %}">home</a>")
```

but it is showing error:-

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/%7B%25%20url%20''%20%25%7D
Using the URLconf defined in example.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
search/ [name='search']
```

I was expecting it will redirect to homepage but.....

Comment: You can only use template syntax inside of templates, otherwise it will just insert the literal text

Comment: did you mean `return redirect("home")`? [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use single quotes (') and  used the reverse function to retrieve the URL for the 'home' view.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse

def search(request):
    home_url = reverse('home')
    return HttpResponse(f'<a href="{home_url}">home</a>')
```